# Google Maps V3 is just a grey box after an ajax query

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap

I have only recently begun to play around with html, javascript, webapps etc and I decided to try write my own Prey standalone webserver.

I am using Twitter Bootstrap for the UI, and jQuery for javascript stuff. [**My reports page**](http://prey-geniass.dotcloud.com/devices/l6wyd/reports.xml) lists all the reports and allows the user to select one to view on the map. The page then gets the data as JSON from the server which all works fine. However when I call `map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(data['lat'], data['lng']))` the map just turns grey instead of moving to that location.

I have tried this in chrome and firefox, and I get the same problem. Strangely, there are no errors in the chrome console-debugger-thing nor in firebug. I can see maybe 10 similar issues under "Similar Questions"; however none of those solutions (eg. CSS) have helped.

Here's the website (it's a sandbox on dotCloud, so it might be very slow): http://prey-geniass.dotcloud.com/devices/l6wyd/reports.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I noticed you store the map object as `window['map']` (funny how *everybody* seems to do that... makes debugging easier when I don't have to dive into the source :) ).

I tried to set the centre myself using a known set of coordinates:

```
map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng('51.0453246', '-114.0581012'));
```

This worked fine, so the actual code is working fine. I tested some cases for incorrect values... `null` and `0` would put me somewhere in the ocean, but `undefined` for both `lat` and `lng` would turn the map grey. Perhaps the values you are passing in are incorrect, and end up being `undefined`?

Looking at the second `alert` that comes, the relevant properties are `latitude` and `longitude`, although you seem to be passing in `data['lat']` and `data['lng']`. Would this be the reason?

This should fix it:

```
//update map
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(data['latitude'], data['longitude']),
    title:"Last Known Position"
});
marker.setMap(map);
map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(data['latitude'], data['longitude']))
// google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

Please note that I commented out your 'resize' trigger (which I assume you probably added in an effort to resolve this problem? I remember suggesting that to another user here :)). It is not required in your case.

Comment: Well that's irritating. I think that's actually an additional problem. what happened there was that the android client uploads the data as 'lat' and 'lng', which I though was crap, so I changed it server-side to latitude and longitude. The problem now, is that data['latitude'] is undefined for some reason. Thanks for the really quick reply though

Comment: I found the underlying cause (see my answer below) but I marked this as the correct answer since, judging by my commit messages, I probably would have given up and posted another question.

Comment: Glad you figured it out geniass :) Your app looks neat! It's very clean, I like that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just found the problem. It was actually server-side where I didn't mark the Response as JSON, so javascript was actually receiving a string, and I was trying to use it as a JSON object. For anyone using Flask, here is the code to do this: 
`return Response(json.dumps(report), mimetype='text/json')`.

Now I don't really now which answer to mark as the correct one (both are technically correct because there were 2 different problems)